# Can I do something like this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<StudentInfo>>" %>

<% int i = 0; %>

<% foreach(var e in Model){%>
<div>
<% if(i==0) { %>
  <% Html.RenderAction("student", "home", new { @et = e}); %>
<% break;
   } %>
    <div>
    <span>
     <% Html.RenderAction("studentDetails", "home", new { @et = e }); %>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<%i++; } %>
```

Here my intension was to execute Renderction Student only once and Studentdetails should be multiple times.

But int value is always taking i =0 bec each time page is loading its considering 0 always.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: sounds like you want to use partial views.

Answer (score 2):

> but int value is allways taking i =0 bec each time page is loading its considering 0 allways.

That's how it works.  That's how pretty much all web platforms work.  Every time your page code you're working a new instance of the object. Once a page request is fully rendered, anything used to build that request that you haven't explicitly saved somewhere like the Session is disposed.